# How to generate a custom picker for Rhapsody tables?

Tags: java, picker, rhapsody

I'm writing a custom picker for an IBM Rhapsody table. The picker is used to select a block (representing a function) which satisfies a specific requirement. I want the picker to only show blocks in the selection tree from a subdirectory, to save about 10 clicks per satisfaction.

I already found this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=46c45210-b12e-4779-aac5-4c22b04c69fb but it is not helping at all, as it doesn't tell how it's done.

This is the current code snippet for the picker:

```
public List<IRPModelElement> pick_3_UserDefinedImplementation(IRPModelElement cellElement, IRPModelElement oldValue){

IRPCollection refCollection = cellElement.getReferences();
IRPDependency dependency = null;
ArrayList<IRPModelElement>  elementList = new AayList<IRPModelElement>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= refCollection.getCount(); i++) 
    {
              if (refCollection.getItem(i) instanceof BLOCKCLASS)  
             { 
                IRPDependency depLink =  (IRPDependency)refCollection.getItem(i);
                elementList.add(depLink.getDependent());
             }
    }
    return elementList;
}
```

I couldn't find the class (or IRPMetaclass) of a Rhapsody block. 
I'm sure there is a smarter way to achieve what I want. 
Has someone already written such a picker and/or can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Block is a "new term" stereotype based on Class.

So you should be able to identify the blocks by:
  1) getting all the classes
  2) iterating over the classes and calling the method IRPModelElement.getUserDefinedMetaClass() to see if it matches Block.